# How do I write logic into a HTML file?

Tags: html, ruby, string

I am trying to populate an HTML file with a few parameters:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>'Breakdown'</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1 'Breakdown'>
            </h1>
  #{a.each do |k,v|
    k.each do |b|
      "<h2 #{a} />"
      "<ol id='resultsFor#{a}'>"
      v.each do |result,number|
      "<li #{number} #{result} />"
      end
      "</ol>"
    end
  end}
        </body>
        </html>"
```

and this is my output:

```
        <html><head>
        <title>Tests Breakdown</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1 'breakdown' >
            </h1>
         abcr11r20r33

        </body></html>
```

where `abc` corresponds to `r1`, `r2`, and `r3` are the result key and numbers are `1,2,3`.

I seem to loose all the additional text in the `each` loops.  The only thing I seem to be getting out of it are the varaibles and not the `<h2>`, `<ol>` or `<li>` tags. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: What is this for `<h1 'Breakdown'>`? Why would you want to do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did was I assembled the string outside of the html.  This allowed me to interchange between ruby code and string text by using the #{} operator.  Then once i have the string compiled with the data I want, I plugged the string into my writer

Answer (score 4):

Although you can try and do this with conventional Ruby inlining using `#{...}`, this tends to be really awkward. It's rare to see this done on large text documents.

The problem you're having here is you can't mix strings and code with plain old string interpolation. You need to have some kind of template language to help you with this, where you can switch between logic and text content.

Using this as an example:

```
"<html>#{ruby_content}</html>"
```

The contents of the `#{...}` block must be a complete block of Ruby code. You cannot interrupt it or split it up. If you're used to something like PHP, where you can switch back and forth, you won't be able to do that here.

There are other ways of expressing this that are easier to manage.

[ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) ships with Ruby and gives you more flexibility:

```
<html><%= ruby_content %></html>
```

Even better is [HAML](http://haml.info) which looks something like this:

```
%html
  = ruby_content
```

HAML might take some getting used to, but it is virtually guaranteed to emit valid HTML documents, saving a lot of time in tracking down improperly closed tags or other random errors that are bound to crop up when writing HTML by hand.

Here's a rough "translation" of your example into HAML:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title
      Breakdown
  %body
    %h1
      Breakdown
    - a.each do |k, v|
      - k.each do |b|
        %h2
          %ol{ :id => "resultsFor#{a}" }
          - v.each do |result, number|
            %li
              = "#{number} #{result}"
```

I'm not sure what you're intending to do with stuff like `<h2 #{a} />` as that isn't valid HTML, or what `<li #{number} #{result} />` means, so you'll have to fix that part.

Comment: HAML is, honestly, the only reason I'm still doing web development. Writing HTML by hand is like working on an assembly line, mind-numbing in comparison.

Comment: Agreed. I was so happy to abandon using ERB-style templates, or writing pure HTML.